# How to animate text with Gradient color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I have written a chunk of code to animate the color of some text on a webpage. Here's how:-

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 spectrum();

 function spectrum(){
    var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
    $('#p1').animate( { backgroundColor: hue }, 2000);
    spectrum();
 }

})
```

Where `#p1` is the identifier of the text block. This code generates a random color and animates the **text** color.
Here's the CSS-

```
#p1 {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: roboto;
    font-size: 96px;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

However, I want to add a gradient to my text using this:-
`background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, red);`

How do I use my `spectrum()` function to animate/change the second color(x) that I have in my `-webkit-linear-gradient(white, x)`

I tried some wild guesses like putting the -webkit line in place of the `backgroundColor` but that didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: There is most definitely an infinite recursion happening here.

Comment: @AustinBrunkhorst yup exactly.. but that's not my question. I know how to change color, but how to change color when a gradient is applied.

Comment: you want gradient to change its color once or many times or based on some time limit?

Comment: @Aravind its a very obvious recursive loop without any counters/conditions

Answer (score 0):

I try this,

```
    function spectrum(){
      var hue = 'rgb(' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ',' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)) + ')';
      $("#p1").css(
        {
          background:"-webkit-linear-gradient(#fff,"+hue+")",
          background:"-o-linear-gradient(#fff,"+hue+")",
          background:" -moz-linear-gradient(#fff,"+hue+")",
          background:"linear-gradient(#fff,"+hue+")"
        }
     );

     }
     setInterval(spectrum,1000);
```

Hope this is what you want 
Check on this link :
http://codepen.io/piyushsharma21/pen/KgxVoV

Comment: Nope this isn't what I want... You are changing the background of the text... I am changing the actual text color

Comment: Actually there is no direct way to add gradient to text in css3 however in -webkit- you can use -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; but it will only work in chrome browser.

Comment: I am doing that already... It makes the text dissappear in some cases